# Sticky header under fullscreen div

Tags: header, scroll, sticky

I have a question about a sticky header. On my website I have a "top" div that contains a 100% width/height image. If the user scrolls down, the top div scrolls away and then they can see the main div/content. But I want to have a "sticky" header just under the top div, so that the user dont see the "menu"-header when they are at the top of the page, it should be sticked just under the top image and hook on when the scrolling is "passing by". is this possible to do?

Thank you in advanced!

Here's a piece of my code. I have fixed so that the meny is right under the top picture, but it doesn't follow the scroll. What's the problem?

Thanks!

HTML:

```
<header id="top">
(The big picture)
</header>

<div id="logo">
<img src="logo" alt="Logo">
</div>

<div class="container">

<div id="sub_header">
    <div id="menu1">
        Content
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#sub_header { height:53px; width: 100%; padding:5px 0; }
#sub_header.sticky { position:fixed; top:100px; left:0px; right:0px; z-index:99999; }
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > body) {
            $("#sub_header").addClass("sticky");
        } else {
            $("#sub_header").removeClass("sticky");
        }
    });
});
```